# Angular.js JSON not showing in ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following controller code:

```
angular.module("MyModule").controller("SideBarCtrl", function($scope, $mdSidenav) {

$scope.menu = [
{
  title: 'Dashboard',
},
// ... More items
```

But I can't get the items to show in my view using ng-repeat. The weird thing is it does the loop and makes the divs, but showing the item data like:

```
      <md-item ng-repeat="item in menu">
      <a>
        <md-item-content md-ink-ripple layout="row" layout-align="start center">
          <div class="inset">{{item.title}} This text shows</div>
        </md-item-content>
      </a>
    </md-item>
```

Just yields the hardcoded text.

I have the controller defined on the body like this:

```
<body layout="column" ng-app="MyModule" ng-controller="SideBarCtrl">
```

I have no idea why it would loop but not be able to show individual JSON items.

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle? It looks fine to me.

Comment: I feel like you should have some sort of errors in the dev console. A fiddle would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem could be the way that you build the angular controller.

```html
<html ng-app="MyModule">
    <head>
        <title>StackOverflow test</title>
    </head>
    <body layout="column" ng-controller="SideBarCtrl">
        <h1>{{hi}}</h1>
        <md-item ng-repeat="item in menu">
          <a>
            <md-item-content md-ink-ripple layout="row" layout-align="start center">
              <div class="inset">{{item.title}} </div>
            </md-item-content>
          </a>
        </md-item>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('MyModule', []);

            app.controller('SideBarCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdSidenav'
              function($scope) {
                $scope.hi= "Welcome to this AngularJS test!";
                    $scope.menu = [
                        {
                          title: 'Dashboard'
                        },
                        {
                          title: 'Anything'
                        },
                        {
                          title: 'Something else'
                        }
                    ];
              }
            ]);
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm actually using angular with meteor so there are some differences there I believe. That's why I haven't created a fiddle yet either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the array of modules that your module depends on, even if it is empty:

```
angular.module("MyModule", []).controller("SideBarCtrl", function($scope) {...
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vvfnN/174/

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't that though.

Comment: The fiddle is working. Please let me know what is different about it and your example.

Comment: I also removed $mdSidenav from your controller since you didn't define it in your example code. I believe that is the only other difference.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured this out. The description didn't mention the fact I as using Meteor. The problem was I had the sidebar in the index file and it wasn't loaded before the data. I moved it to an ng-include in the view and it works fine. Thanks everyone for attempting to help!